# circular imports in Python

Tags: python-3.5

I have two files `pair.py` and `account.py` that have these import statements on top. On top of `pair.py`

```
from models.account import Account
```

and on top of `account.py`

```
from models.pair import Pair
```

They are dependent on each other but I can't seem to do this. What can I do?

When I try to from this from terminal:

```
python3
pair models.pair import Pair
```

I get:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Account' from 'models.account'
```

Comment: Try `import models.account` and `import models.pair`, and then using the names `pair.Pair` and `account.Account`.

Comment: I get pair is not defined.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://gist.github.com/datagrok/40bf84d5870c41a77dc6) would be helpful?